# Select random rows till the sum of column reaches the target in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, sql-server-2022

I need the random rows to be displayed till the target reaches
it should reach the target if there is any possible combination is there.

```
    Id  price 
    1    20
    2    30
    3    40
    4    15
    5    10
.......200+ rows
```

If the target is 30 it should return with

```
id   price
1     20
5     10

or

id   price
2     30
```

If the target exceeds the sum or no combinations --120  in this case it should return till last maximum

```
Id  price 
1    20
2    30
3    40
4    15
5    10
```

If the target is less than the sum --5 in this case it should return nothing

```
Id  price
```

what i tried

```
select t.*(select q.*,sum(q.price) over(order by newid())as total from Orders q)t
where t.total<=45
```

i want rows till the exact target is reached
if there is no possible combinations of getting the exact target then only it has to return till the nearest value to the target

this query is giving me the rows not exactly all the time

Comment: ou can use the window function SUM to get the running sum and then remove all rows that doesn't fitt the number you want  using a rand() as order in the windo function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate a Running Total in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860966/calculate-a-running-total-in-sql-server)

Comment: Feels like a Bin Optimization exercise.  The number of permutations can quickly become astronomical.

Comment: This looks like the Knapsack problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). It is NP complete, which means that if you have any significant number of rows, you will run into performance issues.

Comment: unless you're working with 10 items or so, this problem shouldn't be solved in SQL

Comment: @nbk i got the idea but how to remove the rows that doesnt fit the number

Comment: the sum of all will be calculated in a CTE and the remove all rows that are bigger than the given number

Comment: @siggemannen I have 200+ data rows ..Im sorry i have mentioned a few here

Answer (score 1):

I aggre with @siggemannen that you should do this for very small populations.
Anyway is a nice excercise, here I'm addressing the 4 scenarios.

- If SUM(Price) < TargetPrice return all
- IF MIN(Price) < TargetPrice return nothing
- Calculate all posible combinations of possible SUM(Price) between different rows. IF there is one combination equals to TargetPrice THEN return it. ELSE return all

So the code look like:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (ID INT, Price money )--DECIMAL(10,4))
INSERT INTO @table (ID, Price) VALUES
(1, 20), (2, 30), (3, 40), (4, 15), (5, 10)
DECLARE @TargetPrice Money = 30
IF @TargetPrice > (SELECT SUM(Price) FROM @table) --If the target exceeds the sum
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM @table
END
ELSE IF @TargetPrice < (SELECT MIN(Price) FROM @table) --If the target is less than the sum
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 0 *
    FROM @table
END
ELSE 
BEGIN
    ;WITH cte AS ( -- find all possible combinations recursively 
        SELECT id, Price ,  CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),Id) IdLst
        FROM @table
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT t.id, cte.Price + t.Price  as Price, cte.IdLst + '|' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),t.Id)   IDLst
        FROM cte 
        INNER JOIN @table t 
            on cte.ID < t.ID
    ), EqCombinations AS (  -- keep only the first one that matches the target price 
        SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY IDLst)  rn
        FROM cte
        WHERE cte.Price = @TargetPrice 
    ), Eq AS (  -- pick the first one
        SELECT t.* 
        FROM EqCombinations
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT * FROM STRING_SPLIT(IDLst, '|') parts) p
        INNER JOIN @table t
            ON p.value = t.ID
        WHERE rn = 1
    )
    SELECT * , 'eq' why FROM Eq  -- if the target was matched
    -- else return all
    UNION ALL SELECT * , 'all' why FROM @table WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Eq)
END
```

Comment: Thank you so much  @Luis LL
This is working fine.. till i have few data if i have 100 data it is not executing till after 10 mins
can u give suggestion for that

Comment: 100 items in combinations with each other is a large number. That's why I mentioned 10 items max :)

Comment: It might help a Lil to create primary keys in the temporary tables

Comment: Luis LL, this is an amazing solution. I think it can be made a bit faster if you create PK on ID, and also put an early bail condition in the recursive part of the CTE:   WHERE  cte.Price + t.Price <= @TargetPrice  -- this way, there's no need to continue once you reach the final price

Comment: anything over 30 rows explode in time though

Comment: Thank you, @siggemannen as I agreed with you in the first place, exploding combinations only work with small populations, even if we add the your suggestion for the bail condition in the CTE's WHERE, we still have a combinatory challenge, which by it's nature, is not scalable.

Answer (score 0):

I took your plain text data and turned it into reproducible DDL/DML:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (ID INT, Price DECIMAL(10,4))
INSERT INTO @table (ID, Price) VALUES
(1, 20), (2, 30), (3, 40), (4, 15), (5, 10)
```

It's really helpful to have this in your question.

This was an interesting challenge to solve, I'm not sure I interpreted your requirement exactly, but here's what I understood:

Select a random row, check the new running total against a value, and if it's less get another random (but distinct!) row and check again. Repeat until the first row which puts the running total over the check value.

```
;WITH MinMax AS (
SELECT MIN(ID) AS minID, MAX(ID) AS maxID
  FROM @table
)

SELECT ID, Price    
  FROM (
        SELECT a.ID, a.Price, a.rn, SUM(Price) OVER (ORDER BY rn) AS rTotal
          FROM (
                SELECT t.ID, t.Price, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RAND(CONVERT(VARBINARY,NEWID(),1))) AS rn
                  FROM (VALUES (
                                RAND(CONVERT(VARBINARY,NEWID(),1))
                               )
                       ) A(Rnd1)
                    CROSS APPLY (SELECT minID, maxID FROM MinMax) mm
                    CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 100 1 AS z FROM sys.system_objects a CROSS APPLY sys.system_objects) z
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN @table t
                      ON ROUND(((maxID - minID) * Rnd1 + minID), 0) = t.ID
                 GROUP BY t.ID, t.Price
               ) a
       ) a
 WHERE rTotal < = 50
```

So here we use some voodoo to find rows, and put them into a random order. Next we apply the windowed function ROW_NUMBER to give is a column to preserve that order. Next we can use the windowed function SUM to get a running total, of those rows, in that random order and finally we can compare the running total of each row, in that order, to the check value.

Example output:

| ID | Price |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 30.0000 |
| 4 | 15.0000 |

| ID | Price |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 10.0000 |
| 1 | 20.0000 |
| 4 | 15.0000 |

Comment: thank you for the code  @Patrick hurst  this is working but not all the time if i give 40 it is giving 35 also a value

Id  price 
1    20
4    15

Comment: There isn't any more than could be added after 35, without going over 40.

Comment: YES but i need to have exact sum of 40 if i have the sum of 40 in the data